# Is there a way to retrieve the queue / topic name from IDestination?

Tags: .net-core, nms

I can get `IDestination` from the received `IMessage.NMSReplyTo`. But I'd like to see its name (for logging). Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDestination interface has a method to fetch the [type](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-api/blob/master/src/nms-api/IDestination.cs#L22) of Destination that it represents and from there you can cast to the type of Destination which can then allow you to get the name.  For instance an IDestination that return a type of **Topic** can be cast to an ITopic and from there you can call [TopicName](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-api/blob/master/src/nms-api/ITopic.cs#L25) to read the destination name.  For temporary destinations you don't really need to know the names in most cases as they are generated and their lifetime is linked to the connection.